# Grub configuration issue on persistance install of Ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

I have a old Atom based Asus Laptop which the emmc storage has died in. To continue using it I have been attempting to boot from a persistance USB. This is my process

1. To make it boot (due to the processor) I "respin" the ISO using this: https://linuxiumcomau.blogspot.com/2022/04/customizing-ubuntu-isos-documentation.html
2. Then use mkusb from this guide https://ostechnix.com/how-to-create-persistent-live-usb-on-ubuntu/ to flash the usb and setup persistence
3. When booting I am thrown into the Grub terminal which I wrote "boot" into giving the error "you need to load the kernel first"
4. After running `set prefix=(hd0,gpt3)/boot/grub` & `set root=(hd0,gpt4)` & `insmod normal` & `normal` based on the commands in here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/418401/grub-error-you-need-to-load-kernel-first grub then presents a list of boot options and sucsesfully boots

However, every time I boot I have to write thoes four commands, is there anyway I can skip this stage/update the grub configuration permanently?